# Performance optimization when switching from nested to flat representation (genetic algorithm)

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy, genetic-algorithm

The code below is the core of a Genetic Algorithm (NSGA-II to be precise, without crowding-distance calculation), but I've taken out all the GA-specific parts and made a generic example. I think I've carried over most of the principles/'constraints' from the original algorithm, but I might have missed something.

As you can see in `loop()`, I need to convert a nested list (2-dimensional) to a flat list pretty often and I'm curious of if there are any better ways to do it. I've added some `asserts` so that it's easier to follow the size and type (nested or flat) of the lists.

Since expected size of input is m=100 individuals (`Number`) for 500 generations (loops), speed is important. Memory usage is not that important (although knowing how to reduce it would be interesting), but execution time is.

Any comments performance-related or otherwise are appreciated.

```
from itertools import chain
from timeit import timeit
import logging

import numpy as np


class Number:
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        if value:
            self.value = value
        else:
            self.value = np.random.randint(10)
        self.rank = -1
        self.strictly_better_than_list = None
        self.strictly_worse_than_count = -1

        self.distance = np.random.randint(10)

    def strictly_better_than(self, other):
        # Placeholder for similar inexpensive computation
        if self.value < other.value:
            return True
        return False


def assign_sort_rank(numbers):
    # Needs flat list
    assert isinstance(numbers[0], Number)

    rank_sorted = [[]]
    for number_a in numbers:
        assert type(number_a) == Number, type(number_a)
        number_a.strictly_better_than_list = []
        number_a.strictly_worse_than_count = 0
        for number_b in numbers:
            assert type(number_b) == Number, type(number_b)
            if number_a.strictly_better_than(number_b):
                number_a.strictly_better_than_list.append(number_b)
            elif number_b.strictly_better_than(number_a):
                number_a.strictly_worse_than_count += 1
        if number_a.strictly_worse_than_count == 0:
            number_a.rank = 0
            rank_sorted[0].append(number_a)
    i = 0
    while rank_sorted[i]:
        current_front = rank_sorted[i]
        next_front = []
        for number_a in current_front:
            for number_b in number_a.strictly_better_than_list:
                number_b.strictly_worse_than_count -= 1
                assert number_b.strictly_worse_than_count >= 0, number_b.strictly_worse_than_count
                if number_b.strictly_worse_than_count == 0:
                    number_b.rank = i + 1
                    next_front.append(number_b)
        rank_sorted.append(next_front)
        i += 1
    # The last front will always be empty
    return rank_sorted[:-1]


def random_selection(li):
    # Need flat list ??
    numbers = []
    for _ in range(len(li)):
        numbers.append(np.random.choice(li))
    return numbers


def rank_distance_selection(numbers_1, numbers_2):
    # Need flat lists
    assert isinstance(numbers_1[0], Number)
    if numbers_2:
        assert isinstance(numbers_2[0], Number)

    n = len(numbers_1)  # == len(numbers_2)
    rank_sorted = assign_sort_rank(np.concatenate((numbers_1, numbers_2)))
    new_numbers = []
    added_count = 0
    for front in rank_sorted:
        # This sort is a placeholder for a custom sort that can't be done by 'sorted',
        # but it still sorts by the same value (distance)
        front = sorted(front, key=lambda num: num.distance)
        # Add fronts to empty number pool until no more complete fronts can be added.
        if added_count + len(front) <= n:
            added_count += len(front)
            new_numbers.append(front)
        # Then, add individuals from the last front based on their distance.
        else:
            new_numbers.append(front[:n - added_count])
            break
    # Return nested, rank sorted list
    return new_numbers


def generate_from_numbers(numbers):
    # Takes a flat list, but can be made to work a nested list
    new_numbers = []
    for i in range(0, len(numbers) - 1, 2):
        number_a = numbers[i]
        number_b = numbers[i+1]
        mangled_numbers = mangle(number_a, number_b)
        new_numbers.extend(mangled_numbers)
    return new_numbers


def mangle(number_a, number_b):
    # placeholders for similar computations
    number_1 = Number(number_a.value - number_b.value)
    number_2 = Number(number_a.value + number_b.value)
    return number_1, number_2


def view_numbers(numbers):
    # Placeholder that need nested, rank sorted list
    assert isinstance(numbers[0], list)
    # Numbers should now be sorted ascending in rank, firstly, and within the
    # same rank in ascending distance
    for front in numbers:
        for number in front:
            print(number.value, number.rank, number.distance)


def loop(m=100, n=500):
    a = [Number() for _ in range(m)]
    b = []
    c = []
    for i in range(n):
        print("Iteration:", i)
        b = rank_distance_selection(a, list(chain.from_iterable(b)))
        view_numbers(b)  # A placeholder that needs nested list
        c = random_selection(list(chain.from_iterable(b)))
        a = generate_from_numbers(c)
        assert len(a) == len(list(chain.from_iterable(b))) == len(c) == m, \
            (len(a), len(list(chain.from_iterable(b))), len(c))

loop()
```

Comment: Don't use `assert`. `python -O file.py` and they are all useless.

Comment: I added them in so that the constraints of the original algorithm would be clearer ("this function need that kind of list") as it may not be self-evident in the generic representation above and to make the flow easier to follow ("now the list is in this form")

Comment: That makes sense. Seemed like you were relying on them, on a re-read I understand your intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor change

```
def random_selection(li):
    # Need flat list ??
    numbers = []
    for _ in range(len(li)):
        numbers.append(np.random.choice(li))
    return numbers
```

can be

```
number = [np.random.choice(li) for _ in li]
```

or even

```
number = np.random.choice(li, len(li))  # with optional .tolist()
```

You don't make much use of `numpy`.  I haven't studied the code enough to know where else you can profitably use it.

```
 def strictly_better_than(self, other):
        # Placeholder for similar inexpensive computation
        if self.value < other.value:
            return True
        return False
```

can be simplified to:

```
 def strictly_better_than(self, other):
        # Placeholder for similar inexpensive computation
        return self.value < other.value
```